# Unexpected method call Exception in powermock

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng, powermock, easymock

I have below chain of call for my project

Impl.execute() --> Helper.help() --> Proxy.doOperation()

I am trying to execute test case for Impl.execute() in PowerMock and TestNG. I am getting below exception

```
execute(ImplTest)  Time elapsed: 0.391 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Unexpected method call Proxy.doOperation({clientId=123456}, ""):
Proxy.doOperation({}, null): expected: 1, actual: 0
at org.easymock.internal.MockInvocationHandler.invoke(MockInvocationHandler.java:44)
at org.easymock.internal.ObjectMethodsFilter.invoke(ObjectMethodsFilter.java:85)
at org.easymock.internal.ClassProxyFactory$MockMethodInterceptor.intercept(ClassProxyFactory.java:94)
at com.xxx.xxx.xxx.sync.services.Proxy$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$1937be76.doOperation(<generated>)
at com.xxx.xxx.xxx.sync.services.helper.Helper.getIdFromClient(Helper.java:39)
at com.xxx.xxx.xxx.sync.services.impl.Impl.execute(Impl.java:97)
at com.xxx.xxx.xxx.sync.services.impl.ImplTest.execute(ImplTest.java:130)
```

I have written below code

```
@PrepareForTest({ApplicationContextLoader.class,Helper.class})
@PowerMockIgnore({"javax.management.*", "javax.xml.*","org.xml.*","org.w3c.dom.*"})
public class ImplTest extends PowerMockTestCase {

   @ObjectFactory
   /**
    * Configure TestNG to use the PowerMock object factory.
    */
   public IObjectFactory getObjectFactory() {
      return new org.powermock.modules.testng.PowerMockObjectFactory();
   }

@Test
 public void execute() {

Impl impl = new Impl();

    Proxy regProxy = PowerMock.createMock(Proxy.class);
    PowerMock.expectNew(Proxy.class).andReturn(regProxy);   
    expect(regProxy.doOperation(Matchers.anyMap(),Matchers.any(String.class))).andReturn(someString);
    PowerMock.replayAll();
    Assert.assertEquals(impl.execute(request, ""),"");
    PowerMock.verifyAll();
  }
```

}

Kindly Help

Comment: It would be easier to answer your question with a compilable code sample. Please post your code as an [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem. At the moment, we can't compile due to missing data (`Impl` and `Proxy` definition etc.). But please don't copy/paste tons of code into your question, take the time to create a minimal example for us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this

```
Proxy regProxy = PowerMock.createNiceMock(Proxy.class);
```

when you do `EasyMock.createMock()` in chained methods, it fails as Easymock does not recognize that this method is going to be called somewhere else, but when we do `EasyMock.createNiceMock()` the mocking does not fail on this unexpected method, and the mocking can be executed as we want.

As a matter of fact I had myself toiled around this error for something like a week, and when I found this workaround, it was like a blessing.

Hope this helps!
Good luck!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Raptor Looks like an answer to me. Maybe not a good one, since it's a bit short. But certainly not worthy of your canned comment.

Comment: @Vihar Please expand your answer to explain *why* this is a solution to the OP's problem.

Comment: this failes in verify java.lang.AssertionError: 
  Expectation failure on verify:
    Proxy.doOperation({}, ""): expected: 1, actual: 0

Comment: @Raptor I agree. But you've posted a canned comment that doesn't apply here. Vihar is not trying to request clarification or leave a comment. He's left a poor answer, and a more helpful comment from you might elicit an improvement in that answer.

Comment: @slowhandblues if this fails on expectation error it means there is something wrong with your EasyMock.expect() and your previous error  has been solved

Comment: @Duncan will take care in future to post complete answers

Comment: @Raptor will take care in future to post complete answers

Comment: @Vihar yes there was issue in expect as I was using Matchers from mockito, reolved when used anyObject from EasyMock. Thanks for the help in resolving the original issue